# I want to use same Firebase App with two javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have made a html page `index.html` which include two scripts included firebase app but every time I run the page only one script working and for the other gave me this message `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).`

in two script files I added my firebase App config info:

```
  var config = {
apiKey: "U",
authDomain: "tm",
databaseURL: "ht",
projectId: "tc",
storageBucket: "teom",
messagingSenderId: "58665"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

how can I run two scripts with the same firebase App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one firebase app can be initialized in a single page.
Remove `firebase.initializeApp(config);` to do what you want to do.

Comment: when I removed from one of my script it gave me `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Comment: first I removed it from the second script but didn't work then I removed it from the first script and works fine. Many thanks for help